# Why does my code crash with a floating point exception?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For reasons I can't understand, this crashes with a floating point exception.

This is surprising, because I do not appear to have any floating point operations in my code and I don't set `i` to `0`. I've even added `i * i != 0` to my code to make sure that this is the case.

Please could someone help me?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int A = 42;
    int i;
    i * i != 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 99999999; i++) {
        if (A % (i * i) == 0) {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: [plead read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: What is `i * i != 0;` supposed to do?

Comment: line 2: `i * i != 0;` is useless. 
furthermore, i don't see you dividing in here.

Comment: @Shark modulo 0 raises a div by zero error doesnt it?

Comment: @NickA `i` should be initialized to 1 in the line above, but due to UB involved... thanks btw.

Comment: @Nick A "modulo 0 raises a div by zero error doesnt it?" - no, it invokes "undefined behaviour" which means *anything* could happen.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `cin.get()` functions in a row?

Comment: You code crashes when i = 65536, so you're dividing by 4294967296, which is 2^32. Coincidence? I THINK NOT! It's overflowing, and ending up as 0. I'd add an answer, but it's closed so I can't ...

Comment: I've editted the question to isolate the problem

Comment: i added i*i !=0 thinking it might avoid 0 in the calculation

Comment: I'll edit the question to express that, although it doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 3):

Your code is invoking undefined behavior, because

```
i * i != 0
```

appears before initializing `i`, thus you can understand your program's behavior because there is undefined behavior happening, and one of the things that could happen is that `i == 0` at some point.

Also, the statement does absolutely nothing so it's pointless.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, that's why one of the possible things is that `i == 0` at some point.

Comment: `i * i != 0` - This is defined - it does nothing except doing the calculation and comparison - then throwing away the result

Comment: Obviously. I'm just trying to say that that is not what your answer says. Terminoligy​ and proper language is important and your answer is not clear. That's all.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you for pointing it our, I appreciate your opinion. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi The part I mostly object to is "behavior is explicable" - what does that mean? That's not proper english as far as I know. Do you perhaps mean "behaviour is undefined"? ??

Comment: this is not the problem, although the points are valid, see my other comments on the question :)

Comment: i tried adding that so "i" doesn't somehow become 0. because somehow i was getting 0 in "i" from loop